# When connect fingerprint scanner /zk9500/ to tablet, doesn't ask permission

Tags: android, sdk, fingerprint, biometrics, zkteco

I'm using this fingerprint scanner /zk9500/ first time. i compile jar files.

```
implementation files('libs/zkandroidcore.jar')
implementation files('libs/zkandroidfpreader.jar')
```

So i write this code.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        LogHelper.i("have permission!");
                    } else {
                        LogHelper.e("not permission!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void InitDevice() {
        UsbManager musbManager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED);
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        for (UsbDevice device : musbManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
            if (device.getVendorId() == VID && device.getProductId() == PID) {
                if (!musbManager.hasPermission(device)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
                    musbManager.requestPermission(device, pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But doesn't ask permission. I don't know how to ask permission.

Answer (score 0):

Only "dangerous" permission need runtime confirmation. `ACTION_USB_PERMISSION` is not a dangerous permission.

List of dangerous permissions : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#permission-groups

Comment: @Guest123456789 Is it useful ?